# loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched

Tags: perl

I don't use perl, but I do use Slic3r, which apparently uses perl.

I don't know what has done it, but some update somewhere has broken perl and I have no idea how to fix it. I've searched a lot but most of the 'solutions' I've found assume some understanding of how perl and its packages work. I don't have this.

Somewhere along the way I tried a script called `find-broken-perl-packages` but that didn't work because there is a bunch of stuff I don't have installed (pacman command not found, `/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl` no such directory etc).

I also found another 'solution' that suggested rebuilding everything using `cpan` (I forget the command I ran, it 'worked' and it took F.O.R.E.V.E.R.), but this had no effect either.

Without wanting to offend the perl crowd - I don't really have much interest in learning perl beyond what I need to fix this so I can use Slic3r again.

When I try to run Slic3r, it gives me the error:

```
ListUtil.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xde00080, needed 0xce00080)
```

and if I try to run the `Build.PL` script to rebuild Slic3r, I get:

```
Cwd.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xde00080, needed 0xce00080)
```

*many* times. I don't actually need to rebuild Slic3r, I just thought it might have fixed the issue.

Running Ubuntu 19.04

Updated to add:

I poked at this some more and tried to fix it with cpan (I don't really understand cpan)

```
cpan[1]> upgrade List::Util
```

which wirred at bit, then told me it was up-to-date. But this didn't fix the issue. So I tried

```
> install List::Util
```

but it just complained that it was already up-to-date (makes sense)

so I had a go at

```
> force install List::Util
```

which did a whole bunch of stuff, appeared to be happy but still did NOT fix my problem. I have confirmed that I know nothing about perl.

Answer (score 1):

I had these two variables set in my `~/.bachrc` file, which caused the problem:

```
PERL5LIB
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT
```

The problem was solved by removing them. Afterwards I deleted the folders that they were pointing to.

Comment: The droids you are looking for are in .bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get some help on #perl-help

I have installed Slic3r slightly incorrectly by not using perlbrew, so an Ubuntu update broke the libraries for it.

by deleting the `local-lib` folder, I was able to run the `Build.PL` script to rebuild everything and now it works.

I will try to update this answer if I manage to install Slic3r properly to ensure a true 'fix'.